# Custom Element Illegal Constructor

Tags: javascript, custom-element

This code gives an "Illegal Constructor" Error, can anybody tell me why?

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    // Other things
  }
}

const myFunc = () => {
  const instance = new MyCustomElement();
  console.log(instance);
}

myFunc();
```

Comment: The funny thing with the same issue on my site is that I immediately call `customElements.define()` after defining its class - and much later the call to `document.createElement()` fails because of this exact error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After hours of searching I found that you MUST register the custom element BEFORE you can create an instance of it. I don't think this is in the spec, but this is the case for all browsers, also the error message sucks. I wish chrome would have just said "You must register a custom element before instantiating it" rather than "Illegal Constructor", which tells us almost nothing about what actually went wrong.

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    // Other things
  }
}

const myFunc = () => {
  const instance = new MyCustomElement();
  console.log(instance);
}

// Add this and it will start working
window.customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);

myFunc();
```

Comment: If you to `new` any built in HTMLElement, this error will be raised. Defining the custom element in the registry works around this somehow, but the error you observed is actually raised when the superclass constructor is newed.

Comment: Just want to know when we need this kind of custom element ?

Comment: @SandeshSapkota This element is just an example for this question, it doesn't actually do anything. If your asking what custom elements are for you should probably google it, they are amazing.

Comment: Note (for completeness) that this behavior is specced here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#html-element-constructors

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can create a custom element before it is defined by using `document.createElement()`.

This element will be created as an unknown element and then only upgrade to a custom element when defined.

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super()
    console.log( 'created' )
  }
}

const myFunc = () => {
  const instance = document.createElement( 'my-custom-element' )
  console.log( instance )
  document.body.appendChild( instance )
}

myFunc()

customElements.define( 'my-custom-element', MyCustomElement )
```

Comment: hi just wondering, do you think it's bad practice to use document.querySelector() to get another custom element inside of a custom element? example: Two web component /custom element inside of the normal document and inside of componentA, I use document.querySelector('componentB') to get componentB and do something with componentB, thanks

Comment: @MrBear77 of course you can do it. Note that if they use ShadowDOM you'll have to get the shadowRoot reference before.

Comment: including using this way to pass data? like this code example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373477/best-way-to-pass-receive-data-to-from-other-sibling-components