# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor when using HTMDivElement class in JS

Tags: javascript

[EDIT (2)] The following change gets rid of the error, but the element does not show up in the browser (however it appears in the 'inspector' (developer tools), see image hereunder):

// test.ts (amended version)

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement implements HTMLDivElement {
    align: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.align = "center";
    }
    public connectedCallback(): void {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);

const myElement = document.createElement("my-element");
myElement.style.width = "100px";
myElement.style.height = "100px";
myElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";

// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

[image]

- I have tried to use the JS HTMLDivElement class with the code hereunder
- Is it possible to subclass HTMLDivElement?
- If not, then how does one create (and subclass) a div (or any other HTML element in TS (or JS))?

The command used to compile the TS into JS is:

```
tsc
```

tsc version: Version 4.6.2 / Node version: v17.4.0

(with the config file hereunder)

I get the error message (in all browsers dev tools) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.
    MyElement file:///Users/sergehulne/Documents/code/JS/axino2/test.js:3
    <anonymous> file:///Users/sergehulne/Documents/code/JS/axino2/test.js:11
test.js:3:9
```

// test.ts

```
class MyElement extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public connectedCallback(): void {
        this.classList.add(`myElement`);
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);

const myElement = new MyElement();
// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

// test.js

```
class MyElement extends HTMLDivElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
        this.classList.add(`myElement`);
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
const myElement = new MyElement();
// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

// tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [Custom Element Illegal Constructor](/q/61881027/4642212). Have you tried `document.createElement`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon 1. document.createElement does not allow you to subclass HTMLElement 2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61881027/4642212 does not seem to differ from my code.

Comment: HTMLDivElement is an interface, so you would need to implement it, not extend it.

Comment: I see. I have changed the class as follows: class MyElement extends  HTMLElement implements HTMLDivElement . There's no error message now, but the element does not show up in the browser

Comment: Trying to use `implements` denies the prototypal inheritance Javascript uses. `HTMLDivElement` already extends `HTMLElement` (because that is its prototypal ancestor). Javascript has no concept of keyworded interfaces; this is a classical point where learning TypeScript without properly learning Javascript first creates false assumptions. One of many, many, many reasons I strongly despise TypeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has some problems, and by the looks of it you are unaware that custom elements by default have `display: inline`, and thus don't accept `width` or `height`. This changes when you no longer extend `HTMLElement`, but instead `HTMLDivElement` (because that is still a `div` which by default has `display: block`, and thus, accepts `width` and `height`).

To extend the `HTMLDivElement`, you need to define and use the element differently using the `is`-syntax:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLDivElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('MyElement alive and kicking');
    this.textContent = this.textContent || 'dynamically created';
    this.style.width = "100px";
    this.style.height = "100px";
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  };
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement, { extends: 'div' });

const myElement = document.createElement('div', { is: 'my-element' });

document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

```html
<div is="my-element">declaratively created</div>
<hr>
```

Please note that extending built-in elements is not supported in any Safari version, and probably never will be. If you still want to use it, you'll need a [polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements).

If the only reason you were trying to bring `HTMLDivElement` into play was to get this block level behaviour (which is by the way only thing you gain when extending it instead of `HTMLElement` because `HTMLDivElement` neither has any properties or methods specific to it), you don't have to do that. Just create a so-called autonomous custom element (which has its own tag name), and set its tag to `display: block` via CSS:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('MyElement alive and kicking');
    this.textContent = this.textContent || 'dynamically created';
    this.style.width = "100px";
    this.style.height = "100px";
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  };
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);

const myElement = document.createElement('my-element');

document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

```css
my-element { display: block; }
```

```html
<my-element>declaratively created</my-element>
<hr>
```

Sidenote:

```js
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
```

is totally useless and will be marked a linter error in most eslint configurations, see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-constructor. Just remove such a constructor, it is not needed because it only does what JS will by default do if no constructor has been explicitly defined.

Comment: A big thank to those who have contributed to answering my questions about  extending built-in elements! Thank you for your efforts, your patience, your good will. It was very instructive!

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do the trick to some extents but, as mentioned in the comments, compiling from TS to JS via tsc seems to dump the :`implements HTMLDivElement` part of the initial test.ts class, as a consequence the width and height of the element are ignored.

The result looks like:

```
<div style="background-color: red;">My text!</div>
```

and not like

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;">my text!</div>
```

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement implements HTMLDivElement {
    align: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.align = "center";
    }
    public connectedCallback(): void {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        this.style.width = "100px";
        this.style.height = "100px";
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);

const myElement = document.createElement("my-element");
const Content = document.createTextNode("My text!");
myElement.appendChild(Content);
// connectedCallback is called when appended to another element
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```